# Resolvent of Dirichlet Laplacian via Fourier Transform

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, spectral-theory, laplacian, greens-function

For $-\Delta$ considered as a self-adjoint operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$, one may write it's resolvent as the Fourier multiplier $g(\xi)=(|\xi|^2-z)^{-1}$. Now let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a bounded domain and let $-\Delta^\Omega$ be the Dirichlet Laplacian on $\Omega$, defined, for instance, via the Friedrichs Extension Theorem. Is there an expression for $(-\Delta^\Omega-z)^{-1}$ in terms of the operator $g(\xi)$ and some multiplication operator $f(x)$? If not, can we approximate $(-\Delta^\Omega-z)^{-1}$ by operators of the form $f(x)g(\xi)$? It seems that something like $f(x)g(\xi)f(x)$ might work for $f$ some bump function of $\Omega$, but the fact that $-\Delta^\Omega$ has to be defined abstractly leaves me unsure of the details.

My motivation is that I would like to prove that $-\Delta^\Omega$ has compact resolvent from the fact that an operator of the form $f(x)g(\xi)$ is compact if $f$ and $g$ vanish at $\infty$. Since one usually proves that the resolvent is compact from the Rellich embedding theorem and one can prove this theorem from the above compactness criterion, I have reason to believe this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing the Fourier multiplier as an expression involving the heat kernel:
$$
         \int_0^{\infty}e^{-t(|\xi|^2-z)}dt=\frac{1}{|\xi|^2-z}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I don't really follow. I'm also interested in the corresponding question for the heat kernel of $-\Delta^\Omega$, but it's not clear to me why it is any easier. Would you mind elaborating a bit?

Comment: @user293794 : The integral I gave you is a way to write the Fourier multiplier for the resolvent function. And that reduces things to looking at the inverse transform of a Gaussian.

Comment: I know how to use this integral find an expression for the kernel of the resolvent when $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^d$, but does it work somehow for other domains?